# ffmpeg & watermark issue on convert movie

Tags: ffmpeg

after update of WinFF i get error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinFF\ffmpeg.exe" -t 0:00:25 -y -i "c:\Videos\temp\input.mpg" -f mp4  -r 14 -vcodec libx264 -coder 1 -flags +loop+cgop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 7 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 0 -qmax 69 -qdiff 4 -bf 3 -refs 3 -direct-pred 1 -trellis 1 -wpredp 2 -vf scale=240:180 -aspect 4:3 -maxrate 800k -bufsize 80k -b:v 400k -ar 44100 -b:a 80k -ac 2 -b 650k  -vf "movie="c:\Videos\watermarklogo.png" [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" "c:\Videos\new\output.mpg"
```

error:
Filtergraph 'scale=240:180' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.

i downt know how to fix

Comment: If you're executing from the command line, shift scale=240:180 to after the overlay i.e. `...h-10,scale=240:180[out]"`. Remove the first `-vf`.

Comment: if iremove -vf i get error movie=c:\Videos\watermarklogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]: Invalid argument

Comment: First "vf". The one before scale.

Comment: now error:[Parsed_movie_0 @ 05d37280] Failed to avformat_open_input 'c'
[AVFilterGraph @ 05d368e0] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'c:Videoswatermarklogo.png'
Error opening filters!

Answer (score 0):

The filename has to be escaped inside the filter

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinFF\ffmpeg.exe" -t 0:00:25 -y -i "c:\Videos\temp\input.mpg" -vf "movie='c\:\\Videos\\watermarklogo.png' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10,scale=240:180 [out]" -r 14 -vcodec libx264 -aspect 4:3 -maxrate 800k -bufsize 80k -b:v 400k -coder 1 -flags +loop+cgop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 7 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 0 -qmax 69 -qdiff 4 -bf 3 -refs 3 -direct-pred 1 -trellis 1 -wpredp 2 -ar 44100 -b:a 80k -ac 2 -f mp4 "c:\Videos\new\output.mp4"
```

Comment: now error:[Parsed_movie_0 @ 03dd6860] Failed to avformat_open_input 'd'
[AVFilterGraph @ 03dee0e0] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'd:\\watermarklogo.png'
Error opening filters!

Comment: The colon has to be escaped.

Comment: `:` --> `\:`  - required on Windows